# Is it haram for women to wear trousers?

Tags: halal-haram, women, hijab, clothing

There are some scholars that say that wearing trousers and leggings for women is Haram. And there are some other Muslims that say that it is permissible only if the trousers are not tight and a long shirt is worn with those ones:

1. Is it permissible or not?
2. If it is permissible, are women allowed to pray while wearing trousers and long shirts?
3. Nowadays, modernization is dominating so you see some women (especially during hot seasons) putting on Hijab in styles but they manage to hide the hair but sometimes the neck is showing, is it permissible?

Comment: Arctic weathers can compromise your modesty, if you wear abayas. Coastal winds and gusts can lift up your loose garments and you would thereby need eight strong arms to hold down your hem. Trousers can therefore save your modesty against stormy winds. Besides, in cold countries, trousers protect you from pnemonia, chilblains, frostbites, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. As long as the trousers and legging are not tight but loose on the body, it is permissible.
2. Yes. As long as the women are covering their body, wearing the Hijab and as mentioned above the clothes, are not tight on their body, it is permissible.
3. Yes, the Quran states that women should cover their hair. Many women these days cover their faces with the niqab (like borqah or...). However the Quran does not state that one should, it is a common misconception similar to the neck being shown. So short answer is, yes the neck can be shown.

Answer (score 1):

**1 -** It can be permissible if it isn't seen to the public as trousers..like a long skirt or blouse which is cut from the middle, so as to facilitate your movement and follow the islamic laws both.

> It is permissible for a woman to wear pants when certain conditions are met:
>
> 1. It must be worn under loose covering clothes.
> 2. It must not resemble men's trousers.
> 3. It must not be worn for imitating non-Muslims.

[Conditions to be met when a woman wears pants](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/5521/conditions-to-be-met-when-a-woman-wears-pants)

**2 -** Following the above rules, yes, in shaa' allah.

**3 -** No, it's not allowed for women to show their necks.

> The woman who leaves her house uncovering her head, neck, arms or legs, commits a major violation of the rules of the pure Sharee‘ah(Islamic legislation).

[A Message to the Woman Who Does not Adhere to the Hijab](https://www.islamweb.net/en/article/158760/a-message-to-the-woman-who-does-not-adhere-to-the-hijab)

I greatly advice you to read the above links.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the people saying it is ok for women to wear trousers in public or in front of non mahram men are getting their evidence from. It is quite specific in the Qur'an to wear an outer covering when you go out hence jilbab. Seems too many people want to water Islam down and the sin will be upon them. [Evidence for Jilbab](http://www.muhajabah.com/jilbab.htm)

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if it included evidences supporting your claims.

Answer (score 1):

The woman is allowed to wear a trouser at home in the presence of her Mahrams (Does she can't marry). She is not allowed to do so outside the house or pray in them. Rather, she must cover her body with something on top that covers the trouser - big Hijab.

Praying with long shirts and dress that show the neck are all disallowed in prayer and in public. These links are helpful:

https://www.islamiqate.com/3815/for-woman-newly-converted-islam-what-dress-code-acceptable
https://www.islamiqate.com/987/do-muslim-women-have-to-wear-hijab-head-cover-and-modest-dress

Answer (score 0):

In regard to your three inquiries:

- As an Islamic rule, women must cover all their bodies except “face
  (the circle shape of the face) and hands till wrists (i.e. palm and
  its back, and fingers)”. Commonly it is not haram for women to wear
  trousers. But it would be haram if it is considered as a tight
  trouser, since being tight could make the people (or youth) arousal…
- In regard to your second question, according to the above-mentioned
  issue, it seems that there is no matter to prayer by a trouser which
  is not tight. (Although it is better to prayers and always being by
  Chaador or Aba as a pretty complete veil (in front of non-Mahrams)
- According to the initial formula, as I illustrated, it is obligatory
  for women to cover all of their bodies except those parts which I
  named. But they must cover their neck as well, otherwise they are
  doing a haram practice. And there is no difference if it is even so
  hot. Haram is haram.

**Reference:**

[isna.ir](http://isna.ir/fa/print/92041710712/%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AE-%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D9%85%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%85-%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87-40-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%B4-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87)

Comment: But U see leggings are naturally tight...so what if U wear them with a long shirt?

Comment: while Salah (prayer), if it covers the leg (and if it is not thin), seemingly it can be permissible, (Of course there ought not to be non-Mahram to see... / it is just for prayer (without the attendance of non-Mahram) and if it is not thin ... / Good luck.

Comment: So you mean you have to pray in absence of non-mahram even while not wearing thick clothes

Comment: uh, Sorry, perhaps I didn't explain completely, but I meant: as much as I figured out, they could be haram in front of non-Mahram, since they can stimulate non-Mahram somewhat ...,  but you can say prayer by them if those are thick (when there is n't any non-Mahram / but you can not say prayer if those are thin ... /

Answer (score 0):

I am going to dissect your question into 3 different questions:

1. Is it Haram to wear trousers and leggings if it’s not tight?
   Not Haram you are covered!
2. Is it Haram to wear trousers and leggings if it’s tight?
   Haram if some body parts are able to be distinguished.
3. Is it good to use such kind of Hijab? (I am no longer talking about Haram or Halal, I am talking about good and great)
   You must always be within the boundaries of religion...meaning that your hair, neck, arms... all most be always and always covered. But you can see a 1000 ladies do that in a 1000 different ways. So which one is the best? Which one would have possibly made Prophet Muhammad and Happy? Which would be the most similar to the way Lady Fatima dressed? Which would be the most covered yet acceptable to the area you are living in? المؤمن یقف عند الشبهه a believer stops when facing a doubt... Meaning that if you think that your way of hijab is in a way that Prophet Muhammad would have accepted but not be happy with...then try to do better!

---

One last note: What is the purpose of wearing trousers and leggings?
Is to be socially acceptable? Is it to be more attractive? Is it just to be comfortable with your clothes?

If it’s to be more attractive while still having hijab, then the person needs to think again about their intention of that hijab... because hijab is to cover all kinds of attractions (not to make yourself ugly... but not trying to beautify yourself when covering yourself...Have you seen a lot ladies that unknowingly put on full hijab yet wear make-up and colorly clothes...)

Answer (score 0):

Alliyah made a good point. Trousers aren't permissible. The Qur'an told women to draw their Khimars over themselves were already wearing modest full body clothing.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. The qur'an addressed the people in the language they understood. The point is whether cloths have the same functionality or not. Please add evidences supporting your claims. And read [answer].

Answer (score -1):

If you need to do anything for the sake if Allah s.w,  It is better to leave behind all those seem to have doubt on them and do as most comfortable things. A Muslim girl is not allowed to pray while their legs are not well covered. If thats so, then how about neck,? How about showing their figure by wearing a tight clothes. It is not allowed to show up their parts of their body direct or indirect way.

Haraam is Haraam. A muslim girl is allowed to wear a kind of clothes if and only if it is covered with an allowed clothes over it.

Among the reason of prayers is for us to meet and talk to Allah indirect.... Would anyone like to meet Allah that way Allah told you its Haraam.?

Allahu a'alam

Comment: I suggest you to look here:[How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

It isnt haram to wear pants. I wear pants and leggins every day because I despise wearing skirts and dresses. Pants are much more comfy and easy to do daily activities with.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE.  Generally we expect answers based on evidence from the Qur'an, hadith, scholarly fatawa, etc.  Would it be possible to [edit] to include such evidence please?

Comment: Also, check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Welcome.